# Hello, i want to perform OCR on image i tried the code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am performing **OCR** on an im[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xptp2.png)age, for that i installed pytesseract library, code i have used is requiring one more library "Image", what would be the cmd code in windows for installation that package. I have tried --> "`pip install image`" that's not working, or is this code right
code is this

```
import image
import pytesseract
print pytesseract.image_to_string(image.open('ocr.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the error is appearing because you used lower case `image.open` while in documentation its `Image.open`

**Try this:**

```
import Image
import pytesseract

# Simple image to string
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('ocr.jpg')))
```